# Alternate to LM386 for 3.3V system

Tags: amplifier, speakers, 3.3v, lm386

I'm trying control the volume of a small speaker (8Ω, 1/4W) in a 3.3V system using a potentiometer wheel (10kΩ). I've done this in the past using an LM386 in 5V systems, but the project I'm working on is 3.3V only. I've been browsing Digi-Key for a 3.3V equivalent, but of the ones I've looked at so far (LM4864, LM4862, TPA301, TS34119), I can't seem to understand how to control the volume in their typical application diagrams (with a pot or otherwise).

Does anyone have experience with something like this?

Comment: AT 3.3v you may want a modern class D amp intended for mobile devices, and you'll want one that can drive both sides of the speaker.

Comment: What do you mean by both sides of the speaker, like left and right channels?

Comment: I think he means a BTL (bridge tied load) driver.  It drives one side of the speaker with a signal, and the other side with an inverted copy of the signal.  Eliminates coupling caps and provides 6dB higher output from the same supply voltage.

Answer (score 0):

for TPA301 \$R_F\$ is the volume control

see [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa301.pdf) page 16 figure 26

Comment: Page 10 seems like it just has graphs of the gain vs frequency... but I see your point about Rf being for gain control in the component selection sectiob. So I think I can replace it with a variable resistor? Because their examples all only show a 50k static resistor

Comment: He might have meant page 16.  I'd use a 50K pot with a 5.6K fixed resistor on each side, and the center tap going to pin 4 of the TPA301.  This will satisfy the impedance limitations on page 16.  One 5K connects to the input cap and the other goes to pin 5.

Comment: Do you think a 10k pot would work if I used 1k fixed instead? Just so I have to source a few less parts ;)

Comment: yes I meant page 16 (edit made),  10K might not work as well as the 50K,